# Chrome connects websocket just by pasting URL into navbar

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I recently noticed something with Chrome and Websockets (particularly with node/socket.io) where the browser will connect my socket when I paste the URL to my page into the URL bar (without actually going through with the page request). I can verify this by simply consoling out "Connected!" and "Disconnected" in their respective socket events.

Now, I've read that Chrome has the ability to preload some parts of webpages when they are typed into the URL bar, and I would imagine that this is what is happening, however, the second part to this issue is that when I remove the url from the bar, it does not disconnect. Furthermore, if I even go to another page in that same tab, still no disconnect.

Also, it seems if I re-paste the url into the bar, the server disconnects and then reconnects.

I feel this could be a major hassle with some implementations of sockets (at least mine). Does anyone have more information about this or a way around it? Am I using the wrong events?

Chrome version: 34.0.1847.131